# Generics, Copy Constructor, Clone method

Tags: java, generics, clone, copy-constructor

I'm trying to create a generic container which has a copy-constructor. I'm having trouble using the clone method even though I have coded it in. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class MyBox<T> 
{
    private List<T> list;

    public MyBox()
    {
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
    }


    public void add(T item )
    {
        list.add(item);
    }

    public MyBox(MyBox<T> other) throws CloneNotSupportedException //this is giving me trouble
    {
        for(T item : other.list)
        {
            list.add((T) item.clone());
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get my copy-constructor to work?

Comment: What if you define the MyBox class as: public class MyBox<T extends Clonable>? That should work.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether or not you need to make a *deep copy* of the list? In other words, is it necessary to copy each element of the list too, or can the new list just point to the same elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you don't need to clone the item.

```
public MyBox(MyBox<T> other)
{
    list = new ArrayList<T>(other.list);
}
```

When you add an item from collection A to collection B, the item is now referenced by both two collection A and B.

Answer (score 0):

How about restricting the generic to Clonable, then it's certain that the cloning of the items will be allowed:

```
public class MyBox<T extends Clonable> {
   ...
```

Comment: NOT TRUE. `Cloneable` interface does not have a public `clone` method, and anyway a class that implements `Cloneable` might not have a method to clone. `Cloneable` simply modifies the behavior of the `Object.clone()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public MyBox(MyBox<T> other) 
{
      this.list = new ArrayList<T>(other.getList()); 
}
```

but you must add a getter for your list first in this case.

UPD. this makes shallow copy.

Comment: He seems to want a deep copy of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in Java, there is no generic way to clone an object. Some classes have a public `clone()` method, which allows you to clone, but there is no common superclass or interface with a public `clone()` method. (In fact, because there is no common interface; classes don't even have to call it `clone()`; they could name it `copy()` or something else.) You could use reflection to see if there is a public `clone()` method, but that might be overkill.